# ARC and pointer storing

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

My situation is a bit more complex than what I've seen here before posting, and I'm not really good with memory management.

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` (that we will call `MyCell` here) and I pass its pointer to an `UITableViewController` (`MyController` here) when clicking on it. I pass *the pointer* because I want to call a method of this cell and the reference is only made by copy in Objective-C so it doesn't call the method on the right cell. I have made this:

**`MyController.h`**

```objectivec
@interface MyController : UITableViewController {
    MyCell * __autoreleasing *_cell;
}
-(instancetype)initWithCell:(MyCell * __autoreleasing *)cell;
@end
```

**`MyController.m`**

```objectivec
- (instancetype)initWithCell:(MyCell **)cell {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _cell = cell;
        // Checkpoint 1
    }
}
```

Then I want to use this variable later in my code, for example to define the number of sections:

```objectivec
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Checkpoint 2
    return (*_cell).contents.count; // contents being an NSArray property of the custom cell
}
```

**The issue:** At the "checkpoints" marked here, I have an `NSLog(@"%ld", (unsigned long)(*_cell).contents.count);`, however it shows 2 (the right number) in the first checkpoint, **but 0 in the second checkpoint**, so basically when I click on the cell an empty table view is shown.

I used to pass the cell by copy by storing it in a `nonatomic, strong` property and everything worked well, but by changing the calls from `self.cell` to `_cell` because of the pointer reference, the view is now empty as I said. It is likely a memory management issue, but I have no clue on how to solve it (fairly new to Objective-C, first app).

**N.B.:** I tried to change the `__autoreleasing` by a `__strong`, but this lead to a crash at every access of a property of the `_cell`. I have also tried to use a `nonatomic, assign` property to store it instead of using a ivar but it didn't solve my problem.

Thanks!

*Edit:* Forgot to mention that I call the view controller by using

```objectivec
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[MyController alloc] initWithCell:(MyCell **)&cell] animated:YES];
```

in my previous view controller, in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Then how can I update the "caller" cell `MyCell` from the `MyController` it pushes?

Comment: Your link is very comprehensive thanks. I will probably do a delegate. Also can you explain me shortly how I should refactor my code?

Comment: 1. Don’t use the cell to store model data. If you want to provide it model data so it can configure itself, fine, but it’s not for storage, but rather just for display and capture. 2. If you have “processing” code, that should be pulled out of the cell, too. 3. Delegate-protocol pattern for passing data back from presented view controller back to presenting view controller.

Comment: Thank you very much, will do! Thanks for the time you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

1. The `* __autoreleasing *` pattern serves a very specific purpose, namely where a called method creates an object and needs to update the caller’s pointer to reference this new object. For example, consider an example from the regular expression [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression?language=objc):

   ```objectivec
   NSError *error = NULL;
   NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b(a|b)(c|d)\\b"
                                                                          options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                            error:&error];
   ```

   So, `error` is a `NSError` pointer, and the caller is
   supplying the address to that pointer so that if
   `regularExpressionWithPattern` instantiates a
   `NSError` object, it can update the caller’s reference to point to it.

   The only time you need to employ this “pointer to a pointer” pattern
   is when the called routine is instantiating an object and wants to
   update a pointer of the calling routine. We generally only have to
   use that pattern when you want to return pointers to more than one
   object (e.g. in the case of `regularExpressionWithPattern`, it will
   return a `NSRegularExpression *` pointer, but optionally may also
   want to update the `NSError *` pointer, too).
2. You said:

   > I pass the pointer because I want to call a method of this cell and the reference is only made by copy in Objective-C so it doesn't call the method on the right cell.

   That logic is not quite right. `MyCell *` is a pointer to that
   original object, not a copy of it. You can access it without
   resorting to the “pointer to a pointer” pattern. In your case, if
   you would just use `MyCell *`, not `MyCell * *`.
3. You should not pass a cell reference to this view controller at all ... one view controller should not be reaching into the view hierarchy of another view controller;
4. Table views have all sorts of optimizations associated with cell reuse ... one shouldn’t use a cell beyond interaction in its own table view data source and delegate methods; and
5. One should not use a cell (a “view” object) to store “model” data (what is currently stored in the `contents` property). Do not conflate the “model” (the data) with the “view” (the UI).

---

So, I would suggest a simple pointer (not a pointer to a pointer) to a model object:

```objectivec
@interface MyController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray <ModelObject *> *contents; // or whatever you previously stored in cell `contents`
@end
```

And then:

```objectivec
MyController *controller = [[MyController alloc] init]; // usually we'd instantiate it using a storyboard reference, but I'm gather you're building your view hierarchy manually
controller.contents = self.contents[indexPath.row]; // note, not `cell.contents`, but rather refer to this current view controller’s model, not the cell (the “view”)
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

And for passing data to and from view controllers, see [Passing data between view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5210535/1271826). But, as a general rule, one view controller shouldn’t be accessing the view objects of another.

Comment: Thank you! I understand your point of view and objc conventions. I did my cell like that because I didn't want to create a model for each custom view, as I do a lot of them.
Also your solution would not work because I want to call a method from `MyCell` and I can't without a pointer reference... I have also other properties in `MyCell`, and that's why I passed the cell itself, to use its properties plus being able to call a method from it.

Comment: The method of my cell I want to call does some process and set the text of a label of the cell, that's why I need to call it

Comment: Views are neither for the storage of model data nor for the processing of that data. But I get it, that you don’t want to tackle the broader architectural design at this point. Understood and good luck